# Custom component method encodeBegin

Tags: html, jsf

In the book `David Geary, Cay S. Hortsmann- Core JavaServer Faces 3rd edition 2010` at the 424 page written the following:

```
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String clientId = getClientId(context);
    // Encode input field
    writer.startElement("input", this);
    writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, null);
    Object v = getValue();
    if (v != null) writer.writeAttribute("value", v, "value");
    Object size = getAttributes().get("size");
    if (size != null) writer.writeAttribute("size", size, "size");
    writer.endElement("input");
    ...
}
```

But the `type` attribute is necessarily for `input` tag. Why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `type` if you want a text input.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) :

> type = text|password|checkbox|radio|submit|reset|file|hidden|image|button [CI]
>       This attribute specifies the type of control to create. The default value for this attribute is "text".

Answer (score 1):

It creates a input field without functionality like a white box with `value` as text and a maximum of `size` letters. In HTML5 the default type is `text`.